# sum comma separated values with certain string

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheet, I have a list of values that includes percentages and numeric values. Here is the list:

```
A1: (12%,3,10%,2,3%,1,6%,4)
```

I need to calculate the following:

1. The sum of all the percentage values.
2. The sum of all the numeric values.

The result should be displayed as:

```
B1: (31%,10)
```

The result should be in one cell and comma-separated.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,split(A1,","),
       arrayformula(join(",",{to_percent(sum(if(right(Σ)="%",Σ,))),sum(if(right(Σ)<>"%",Σ,))})))
```

***arrayformula style:***

```
=map(A:A,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="",,let(Σ,split(Λ,","),
       arrayformula(join(",",{to_percent(sum(if(right(Σ)="%",Σ,))),sum(if(right(Σ)<>"%",Σ,))}))))))
```

[image]